# Exchange 2007 Outlook refuses to point to new Public folders

Tags: exchange-2007

I have moved our exchange server from 2007 to 2007 (bigger server) everything has gone great, but just before I turn off the old machine, I notice that outlook reports in its connections that it's still using the old server for its Public Folders (yes I have moved them to the new server)

Question is: If I just uninstall the old server will this update whatever outlook uses to see where the public folders are?

Or does anyone know where that setting is? I am worried about removing the old server and losing access to the public folders.

Thanks all

BTW just found this site, 'tis great!

Comment: How did you move your public folders to the new server, what command?

Comment: Sam,

In the Exchange power console thingie, i used this command. This one moves ALL the PF's from one server to the other.

MoveAllReplicas.ps1 -Server Server01 -NewServer Server02

You can also use the Public Folder GUI in the Tools section of the exchange management GUI. You select the public folder, click the replication tab, add the new server (wait 24hrs) then remove the old server from the replication list. Then u can point the mailstore to the right Public folder server.

Either way has now worked for me. I am sure there are better though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the public folder that is specified in your mailbox store. This needs to point to your new PF structure on your new server.

After you have done this you also need to move all replicas from the old server.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I feel a bit of a numpty, went Exchange blind i guess :)